# Adding a column outside the hierachy in SSAS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have a report that is suppose to compare Quotes to Orders.

It currently has a simple hierarchy Year->Month->SuccessfulQuotes and then a column to the right that has the Count of Successful Quotes.

I'd like to just add another column directly to the right of it, that contains a measure for the Count of All Quotes.  Is this possible?

I have been attempting to understand the logic of SSAS for several months now, and have the impression that reports typically are hierachical in nature, and that since Successful Quotes is in the hierarchy, then I cannot display the total unless I change the structure of the hierarchy.

Managers do not care whether a report is hierarchical or not.  They just want a column added to the right, which I could do if this were a programming language.  Isn't SSAS restrictive in this sense?

Answer (score 0):

I completely understand your issue.  Due to the relationship of the count to your hierarchy it is dividing up the counts among your different levels of your hierarchy.

```
i.e.

Year1  Month1 SuccessfulQuotes1 Count = 7 
Year1  Month2 SuccessfulQuotes1 Count = 10 
Year1  Month3 SuccessfulQuotes1 Count = 14

etc.....Right
```

The only way I can think of you getting this to work off the top of my head is by having the same count in a table that is not directly related to your hierarchy (table).  As when a relationship does not exist SSAS just shows the total of your sum and does not splice by your attribute.

That being said, I am guessing that is far from best practices (and may not work for you if you are also using a filter)

All of this being said, there is probably a better way of doing this I am also rather new to SSAS/MDX.  HTH

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution, but it sounds promising.  Is that like having a table within a table?  I'll probably have to approach this with a fresh mind tomorrow.  It's frustrating coming from a programming background where I could just put anything anywhere.

Comment: I hear you as far as lack of mental capacity at the end of the day.      Again, I don't think this is best practices but it might get you over this little hump.  You would have another table with the count present in that table (basically a duplicate table) that was not related to your hierarchy.  So, when you pull in the count from the duplicate table it doesn't divy up the count amongst your hierarchy levels.

Comment: On my way home now so I can't try it, but if I understand correctly, would this second table be able to respond to expanding and collapsing columns in the first table?  I've thought about doing this in the past.  I might need to backtrack and show All in my report, and then sum calculated measure for the Successful quotes, which might be the standard approach, but seems pretty lame in that it is so indirect.  Your solution is more direct.

Comment: Not sure on expanding and contracting columns in the first table.